# What would be the proper way to tune Apache Spark for responsive web applications?

Tags: apache-spark

I have previously used Apache Spark for streaming applications where it does a wonderful job for ETL pipelines and predictions using Machine Learning.

However, Spark for EDA may not be as fast as one may want. For example, if you would like to do basic mathematical operations on data coming from Postgres or ElasticSearch using the data frames in Spark, the time it takes to fetch data from the host system and do the analysis is much higher than that taken by the SQL query on Postgres to run.

Even simple aggregations such as `sum`, `average`, and `count` can be done much faster using SQL than doing them on top of Spark-SQL.

From what I understand, this is not because of latency in fetching the data from the host system. If you call the `show` method on a data frame, you can quickly get the top rows of the data set. However, if you limit the response in SQL, and then call `collect` the time taken is huge.
This means that the data is there, but the processing being done while calling `collect` is taking a time.

Regardless of the data source (CSV file, JSON file, ElasticSearch, Parquet, etc.), the behavior remains the same.

What is the reason for this latency on `collect` and is there any way to reduce it to the point where it can work with responsive applications to make real-time or near real-time queries?

Comment: First, your question is off-topic for being too broad to answer. Second, reading the official documentation would have helped you understand what collect does. Third, your assumption is incorrect, transporting data over the network is a bottle neck. Fourth, Spark isn't designed for responsive web application, even thought it can fit perfectly as part of the system e.g Lambda architecture. You always need a layer service on which queries responses are short. And last, I may ask, what's your background with Big Data Analytics or BI applications for such claims ?

Comment: If you are already using Spark Streaming, why not use something like Apache Kafka as the connector between your web server and your Spark application? I currently use `NodeJS` and `kafka-node` to write incoming requests to Kafka, then pick them up in Spark, process them, and write the results back to Kafka. All in real time. Works fine for me.

Comment: I agree with @eliasah, but have a pointer here that, Spark is memory hungry, try increasing RAM and see the difference in processing time. As far as collect is concerned, that is when actual processing is happening and DAG gets materialized, so never blame collect().

Comment: @DavidGriffin spark-streaming isn't fit for most exploratory data analysis (EDA) tasks. The solutions would be to level between spark-streaming and spark (batch) + a service layer with precompute and updated analytics. Nevertheless I like your idea !

Comment: Like I said -- works fine for me.

Comment: As for 'collect' , you need to perform aggregation, summary, bucketization when it comes to deal with Big Data representation. There is whole theory about approximation and discretization techniques to be applied in this case. Here is an example about [Interactive audience analytics with Apache Spark and HyperLogLog](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/10/13/interactive-audience-analytics-with-apache-spark-and-hyperloglog.html) I advise you to read.

Comment: @DavidGriffin you perform EDA with that architecture ? :)

Comment: Sure. Took me about a year to figure out how to do it. Literally a year. But it's doable.

Comment: I've very curious about the solution. @DavidGriffin Would it be possible for you to share more details ? Not on SO Ofc. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I hope everyone is reading about it in the near future. :-)

Comment: Can you share your contact with me on Twitter in a DM https://twitter.com/elieah ? @DavidGriffin :)

Comment: If you look at my profile here on SO I have my LinkedIn info. Hit me up on LinkedIn?

Comment: @DavidGriffin Done ! ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113675/discussion-between-david-griffin-and-eliasah).